# Производительность и выборка из многомерного массива

Tags: php

Как лучше выбрать ветку многомерного массива с точки зрения производительности:

```
   $records = $records[1]
```

или

```
 $newVar = $records[1]
```

чтобы далее её использовать

```
 foreach ($records as $value)...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$records = array(...)

foreach ($records['1'] as $value)
```

Comment: Просто не хотелось писать дополнительного индекса при использовании отдельной ветки многомерного массива.
Хотел взять что-то вроде ссылки на кусок массива и дальше с ним работать. Разве в этом случае: <pre>$records = $records[1]</pre> происходит копирование?

Comment: тогда ссылку пишите

    $newVar = &$records[1]

Comment: http://ideone.com/IJpuUA

Comment: Спасибо, исчерпывающие комментарии и ответ на вопрос